# What's the origin of the phrase - "For the life of me"?

Tags: etymology

The [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for-the-life-of-me) definition is:

> (informal) However hard I try; even if my life depended on it

I have come across this phrase quite a lot of times in [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22For+the+life+of+me%22):

- For the life of me, I can't remember that word...
- I can't, for the life of me, find an idiom...

and so on.

I tried to visualize it via [Ngram plots](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22for+the+life+of+me%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1750,cd_max:1833&lr=lang_en&safe=active&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=d-K6VtqlHIeLuASRpbygCg) and it indicates that the usage started somewhere around early 1760s but can't pin-point an exact source or timeline.

#### **Is there any interesting etymology behind this expression?**

Comment: An early example is from "The World" 1755: -  "*for the life of me I could not forbear pursuing my blow;  and therefore  ordering my servant to light him home*" -  https://books.google.it/books?id=l_ZWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA63&dq=%22the+life+of+me%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-zJjO2OzKAhWBB5oKHYvmB40Q6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=%22the%20life%20of%20me%22&f=false - I appears that the expression was already in use at that time.

Comment: It is an idiom and it took me a while to find a formula where one can connect the preposition for and "life of me". I think the idea behind this idiom might be explained with: Even if I had to pay for it with my life/with the life of me whether I can answer the question or not, I can't give an answer.

Comment: @rogermue That's what I was going to say  -  agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*OED* has an entry for:

> ***for (one's) life*** (also ***for dear life***, etc.): as if, or in order to, save one's life.

and adds that:

> Also hyperbolically in trivial use: ***(I cannot) for my life, (I cannot) for the life of me.***

The early forms *for (one's) life* and  *for dear life* were used literally  and OED's earliest example is from c1275:

> Þat he ne miȝte for his liue Iso þat man wiþ hire speke.
>
> <sub>*John Henry Grafton Grattan · The Owl and the Nightingale.*</sub>

OED's citation from 1632 might be the first idiomatic usage:

> For my life I could neuer attaine to any perfect knowledge thereof.
>
> <sub>*William Lithgow · The totall discourse..of..trauayles, from Scotland, to..Europe, Asia, and Affrica*</sub>

Comment: Wow! That's a nice answer... But can you please add the modern translation of "*Þat he ne miȝte for his liue Iso þat man wiþ hire speke.*"

Comment: @BiscuitBoy: "That he could not for his life is that man with her speaks..". Actually this usage can be idiomatic too.